# Clipping a video with just some words of a sentence in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a sentence inside a p tag and I want that only some words of this sentence can clip a video.
I made an image to show what I mean:[image: Video clipping with some words]

Is it possible to achieve this with simple CSS?

Thank you in advance :)

Note: background is #171717, so I can't use mix-blend-mode:darken

Comment: You can set the video as background and then set the character with transparent color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the word which you want to clip by putting that inside span like this.

```
<p>Stackoverflow <span>is awesome</span> </p>
```

I hope this below example help you to make it happen.

https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/aONdzJ?editors=1100